# Using latexrelease's \IncludeInRelease in packages?

Tags: package-writing

Reading the docs on the latexrelease package I see that there is a system for the latex kernel which lets users simply pass a date argument (presumably the date their document was successfully compiled to the intended output) to specify the version of the latex kernel that the user wishes to use.

Currently, I handle backwards compatibility for my package with versions, e.g., I have options compat31, compat32 etc.. which lets the user specify they want to use the code as it existed at that version.  Should I be using the \IncludeInRelease functionality from latexrelease in a package or is that only for kernel developers?  If not is there another standard way to do release versioning by date?

If non-kernal packages should use \IncludeInRelease then what is the functionality of the optional argument?  The docs say "For this reason \IncludeInRelease has an optional argument that specifies an alternative date to use if a date option has not been specified to latexrelease" but then they seem to suggest that given the following code (after 2015/01/01??) as long as latexrelease isn't loaded with a date equal to or earlier than 2015/01/01 the empty block below will execute which is the opposite of what I would expect if 2015/01/01 is functioning as the date used if the date option is left unspecified.

```
\IncludeInRelease{2015/03/01}[2015/01/01]{\widget}{Widget Definition}
\EndIncludeInRelease

\IncludeInRelease{2015/01/01}{\widget}{Widget Definition}
\def\widget{new version}%
\EndIncludeInRelease
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to use `\IncludeInRelease` in packages but (having tried it:-) I don't recommend it. We introduced a related mechanism that works better in a package context with package rollback.

See ltnews issue 28 "A general rollback concept for packages and classes"

You can also look at (for example) `array.sty` in the tools bundle where this is used.

`array.sty` starts

```
\providecommand\DeclareRelease[3]{}
\providecommand\DeclareCurrentRelease[2]{}

\DeclareRelease{}{2016-10-06}{array-2016-10-06.sty}
\DeclareRelease{v2.4}{2020-02-10}{array-2020-02-10.sty}
\DeclareCurrentRelease{}{2020-10-01}
```

If you use

```
\usepackage{array}
```

You get the current version

but

```
 \usepackage{array}[=v2.4]
```

or

```
\usepaackage{array}[=2016-10-06]
```

will load the saved older version, with the version checking and loading being handled by LaTeX's core package loading code, not the array package itself, other than declaring the versions available.

Comment: Thx greatly..that sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.  In case anyone else is looking for the docs you mentioned they are here:. https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2018-FMi-TUB-tb122mitt-version-rollback.pdf